# Python 2.7 - Identify Pathogenicity Islands - Calculate GC Content Across Sections of a String

Tags: python, python-2.7, bioinformatics, biopython

I am trying to write a function that looks at a segment of a longer string, calculates the GC content and then moves on the the next segment and so on.

I already have a function that calculates the GC content. I am having trouble writing the part of the function that isolates a segment of a longer string.

For example: I have the string 'TATAGCATCGATCTCTGACGTATCGATCGATCGTCTATATA' I want the function to look at the first 5 indexes, call my existing function to calculate GC content, and move on to the next 5 indexes and so on until the end of the string.

This is my function for calculating GC content.

```
def GCcont(DNA):
    '''calculate GC content'''
    counter=0
    for nuc in DNA:
        if nuc=='G' or nuc=='C':
            counter=counter+1
    return counter/float(len(DNA))
```

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way:

```
def get_gc_across_sections(s):
    sections =  [s[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(s), 5)]
    return [GCcont(section) for section in sections]
```

By the way, it is common practice to use snake case, as opposed to camel case, for function names in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the snake vs camel case. I see that this is analogous to what is in the PEP 0008 Style Guide. The book I am working with consistently uses the camel case convention.

Comment: No problem! Yes that's correct. I'd say most Python programmers adhere to either pep-8 or the Google Python style guide, both of which advocate this naming convention. Staying consistent in whatever style you choose is probably more important though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a generator that spits out blocks of your DNA sequence:

```
def section(dna, blocksize):
    start = 0
    while True:
        end = start + blocksize
        yield dna[start:end]
        if end > len(dna):
            break
        start = end
```

It works like so:

```
>>> dna = 'TATAGCATCGATCTCTGACGTATCGATCGATCGTCTATATA'
>>> list(section(dna, 5))
['TATAG', 'CATCG', 'ATCTC', 'TGACG', 'TATCG', 'ATCGA', 'TCGTC', 'TATAT', 'A']
```

Then computing your GC content for each block is as simple as:

```
>>> [GCcont(block) for block in section(dna, 5)]
[0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.6, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.0, 0.0]
```